# confusing behavior of `++` syntax in pgfplots/tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, draw

I thought I understood how the `++` syntax in tikz/pgf works, but apparently, I don't. Consider the following example code which, according to my understanding, should produce two vertical blue lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    domain=1:4,
]
\addplot[red] {0.5};
\draw[blue] (axis cs:2.5,0.0) -- ++(axis cs:0,0.5);
\draw[blue] (axis cs:1.5,0.0) -- ++(axis cs:0,0.5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the result looks like this:

[image: strange]

The blue lines are tilted. Why is that?

Comment: where is `(axis cs:0,0.5)` right now in this view? That zero belongs to y axis but not x axis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the `axis direction cs` for the relative coordinates:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    domain=1:4,
]
\addplot[red] {0.5};
\draw[blue] (2.5,0.0) -- ++(axis direction cs:0,0.5);
\draw[blue] (1.5,0.0) -- ++(axis direction cs:0,0.5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]